# Isodate package: package loading vs. \AtBeginDocument

Tags: package-writing, isodate

In order to have iso dates on my class-generated title page, I would have to load `isodate` before calling `\AtBeginDocument` since this MVE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
                                  % good position for isodate
\AtBeginDocument{\today}
\usepackage[ngerman,iso]{isodate} % bad position for isodate

\begin{document}
\par\today
\end{document}
```

generates this undesirable output

[image]

However, my corporate style class does not load `isodate` by default and I would like to leave this up to the user of my class in case they want iso dates -- which produces the situation shown.

I understand that the order of package loading and defining commands sometimes is crucial. I would like to know if there is any way to circumvent this problem. Can I do anything to load `isodate` after using `\AtBeginDocument`?

Comment: The cheap way out is to add an option to your class to load `isodate`. If the user wants ISO dates she sets the option, `isodate` is loaded before `\AtBeginDocument`, everything is fine. If she doesn't want ISO dates, she doesn't set the option, no `isodate` is loaded (and the user has no reason to load `isodate` later manually), everything is fine again. Of course that requires documentation (*if you want ISO dates, use the option, don't google stuff and use that*), but might be better than nothing.

Comment: In this case the issue is that `isodate` does its own setup in `\AtBeginDocument` and depending on the order you come in before that or too late. You could of course try to start there and try to manipulate the hook (similar to say https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/464682/35864). Or you could try to detect if the package has been loaded after your `\AtBeginDocument` hook and try to salvage the situation then. But all that is probably going to get really messy.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell users to load the package before the class:

```
\RequirePackage[ngerman,iso]{isodate}
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\AtBeginDocument{\today}


\begin{document}
\par\today
\end{document}
```

But adding a date option to the class would be better, if that is a possibility.

Comment: +1 for the option.