# Removing the content of a LaTeX hook (using lthooks)

Tags: latex-base, hooks, shipout, lthooks

In a special case (new version of the document class `leaflet`) I use the new LaTeX hook `shipout/before` to save the finished pages in box registers without output. In the next step they are combined and output. At this point, I want none of the shipout hooks to be active anymore. How can I achieve this? Are there any associated token registers that I can reset?

Comment: Doesn't `\RemoveFromHook` work?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want to do, but you can see the contents of the hook with `\ShowHook{shipout/before}` then remove a specific label with `\RemoveFromHook{shipout/before}[<label>]` or `\RemoveFromHook{shipout/before}[*]` to clear all code(!) from it, but that might be a bad idea if other packages add code to that hook

Comment: Thank you Phelype. `\RemoveFromHook{...}[*]' is the right thing in this case.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been resolved in comments.

Comment: @rolfn I added an answer explaining the different methods and what they do exactly.  Hope it's clear enough

Answer (score 6):

It depends a bit on what you want to do.  With the new hook management system, packages add labeled code chunks to the hooks, and you can manipulate those chunks independently by using their label.  To find out what a hook contains you can use `\ShowHook`.  Here's an example from the documentation ([`texdoc lthooks`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/lthooks-doc.pdf)):

```latex
-> The hook 'example-hook':
> Code chunks:
>     foo -> [code from package 'foo']
>     bar -> [from package 'bar']
>     baz -> [package 'baz' is here]
> Extra code for next invocation:
>     -> [one-time code]
> Rules:
>     foo|baz with relation >
>     baz|bar with default relation <
> Execution order (after applying rules):
>     baz, foo, bar.
```

which means the hook contains three code chunks (labels `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`—they usually have the same name as the package that added them).

How there are four ways you can remove any single code chunk:

1. You can, in your package (let's say it's `foo` here), add your code to that hook using `\AddToHook`, then declare a rule that your package will remove the code chunk from (say) `baz` by using

   ```latex
   \DeclareHookRule{example-hook}{foo}{voids}{baz}
   ```

   then in the `example-hook`, when your package `foo` is present, the code chunk for `baz` isn't used.
2. In case your package `foo` is not at all compatible with `baz`, then you can write

   ```latex
   \DeclareHookRule{example-hook}{foo}{incompatible-error}{baz}
   ```

   and both code chunks for `foo` and for `baz` are dropped if both exist in `example-hook`. There is also `incompatible-warning`, if it's not a breaking incompatibility.

In both cases you can also use `\DeclareDefaultHookRule{foo}{<relation>}{baz}` and it will affect packages `foo` and `baz` in *all* hooks (though non-`Default` rules have precedence).  Also in both cases, the setting can be overridden with another `\Declare(Default)HookRule` or `\ClearHookRule`.

3. If you *really* want to remove the code chunk for package `baz`, then you can do

   ```latex
   \RemoveFromHook{example-hook}[baz]
   ```

   But this operation, different from setting a rule is destructive and cannot be undone.  `\RemoveFromHook` also works if the label wasn't yet added to the hook.
4. Finally, if you want to completely clear a hook, for whatever reason, then you can do

   ```latex
   \RemoveFromHook{example-hook}[*]
   ```

   which will remove *all* code chunks from `example-hook`.  But this operation is not recommended, because it will remove all code that was added to the hook until that point, regardless of what that code is.  As for the previous case, this action cannot be reversed.  So use this only if you really mean to completely clear the hook, otherwise try to build on the approaches outlined above.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.