# \renewenvironment and environment hooks

Tags: latex-base, hooks, lthooks

This question refers to the hook system of LaTeX 2e introduced in October 2020 (`lthooks`).

How does `\renewenvironment` interact with its hooks?

- Are the hooks cleared or does the code already added to the hooks remain?
- When the original definition of the environment is restored (e.g. by ending the group), are the hooks restored to their old values?
- Do the answers to these questions also apply to the `document` environment, or does it behave differently in this respect?

Comment: Would you really like to do `\renewenvironment{document}`? I hope not.

Comment: @egreg I took over the `subfiles` package some time ago. In one way or another I have to deactivate certain `\begin`/`\end{document}`s. Similarly the other packages of the `subdocs` group on CTAN. I need to understand the effects of different options.

Comment: The environment hooks are applied by name. If you do `\AddToHook{env/quote/before}{\small}`, the code will be executed whatever is the current definition of `quote`.

Comment: @egreg Thx, this gives me some idea of how it works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll try to answer your questions one by one.  First, for context:

The hooks are executed by `\begin` and `\end`.  The environment code is not changed in any way.  With `lthooks`, `\begin` does (way oversimplified)

```latex
  \UseHook{env/#1/before}%
  \begingroup
    \UseHook{env/#1/begin}%
    \csname #1\endcsname
```

and `\end` does

```latex
    \UseHook{env/#1/end}%
  \csname end#1\endcsname
  \endgroup
  \UseHook{env/#1/after}%
```

where `#1` is the environment name.  This is basically the same layout as the `etoolbox` hooks were before `lthooks`.

> - Are the hooks cleared or does the code already added to the hooks remain?

They remain.  Whatever was added to `env/foo/before` will be executed at `env/foo/before` regardless of the definition of the environment.  The way it is, it is not possible for the hook code to know that `\foo` was redefined between two points in the document.

> - When the original definition of the environment is restored (e.g. by ending the group), are the hooks restored to their old values?

Operations on hooks are always global, so adding code inside a group is not restored at the end.  Rather you have to explicitly remove it, if you need to (see my answer about [removing code from hooks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/566686/134574)).

> - Do the answers to these questions also apply to the document environment, or does it behave differently in this respect?

`document`, as an environment, has all the hooks that usual environments have (except for `env/document/after`, which is not executed because the TeX run is ended before that).  But `\document` the macro has also a bunch of additional hooks that are coded into the macro:

- `begindocument/before`: the first thing executed by `\document` (after the `\endgroup` that cancels the `\begingroup` done by `\begin`).  This is a “one-time” hook, which means that any `\AddToHook{begindocument/before}{<code>}` after this point will cause the `<code>` to be executed immediately;
- `begindocument`: the good'ol `\@begindocumenthook` (you can add code to it either with the new `\AddToHook` interface or with `\AtBeginDocument`).  This is also a one-time hook; and
- `begindocument/end`: the last thing executed by `\document` except for the final `\ignorespaces`.  Also a one-time hook.

If you redefine `\document`, the environment hooks will execute normally as for any environment, but the `\document`-specific hooks will not (unless you add them to your redefinition, of course).