# Wrapping the document environment into another environment fails since LaTeX Update of October 2020

Tags: errors, environments, updating, lthooks

Since the last LaTeX Update, wrapping `\document` into another environment fails, possibly because of the new hook management system.

The following used to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{mydoc}{%
  \document%
  }{%
  \enddocument%
}%


\begin{mydoc}

This is a test document.

\end{mydoc}
```

I use this mechanism since nearly 20 years to create math exercises for students which can be compiled standalone or included into other documents (varying the `mydoc` environment).
Since updating today, I get

> LaTeX Error: \begin{mydoc} on input line 13 ended by \end{document}.

Since I have about 1000 such documents, I would really appreciate a (new?) way to wrap the `document` environment into a private one.

Comment: `\AddToHook{env/mydoc/before}{\begin{document}} \AddToHook{env/mydoc/after}{\end{document}}` works, depending on the timing you need

Comment: alternatively `\let\mydoc\document   \let\endmydoc\enddocument` would work in old or new formats

Comment: Also `\newenvironment{mydoc}{\endgroup\document}{\enddocument}` seems to work.  But again, depends on what exactly you do to `\document` in your custom environment.  Could you clarify, please?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Just tested it (your first code) for my applications and it works smoothly. You saved my day! Please provide this as an answer. I should familiarize myself with the new hook system (read about it today for the first time).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That would not work for me, because in my application `mydoc` contains some more code.

Comment: sorry previous comment was nonsense, I deleted it:-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends what exactly your `mydoc` environment does with `\document` and when.  If you just want for

```latex
\begin{mydoc}
  ...
\end{mydoc}
```

to be a shortcut for

```latex
\begin{document}
  \begin{mydoc}
    ...
  \end{mydoc}
\end{document}
```

then you can do

```latex
\AddToHook{env/mydoc/before}{\begin{document}}
\AddToHook{env/mydoc/after}{\end{document}}
```

and it will execute `\begin{document}` right before `\begin{mydoc}`, and `\end{document}` right after `\end{mydoc}`.  See my answer on the [timing of the environment hooks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/566737/134574).

You can find the documentation for `lthooks` [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/lthooks-doc.pdf) (or with `texdoc lthooks`).

---

This is equivalent to the interface previously provided by `etoolbox`:

```latex
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{mydoc}{\begin{document}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{mydoc}{\end{document}}
```

except that now it uses `lthooks` rather than patching `\begin` and `\end` (which would often lead to

```
Package etoolbox Warning: Patching '\begin' failed!
(etoolbox)                '\BeforeBeginEnvironment' will not work.
```

if any slightly incompatible package were loaded).

Comment: Thank you for your really helpful answer (and linking to your *timing* answer).